# How to generate html test report for junit in sbt?

Tags: scala, junit, sbt, scalatest

I have junit tests in my scala sbt project.

I know, that I can generate html reports for ScalaTest with:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/test-reports")
```

But how to generate html for junit tests?

Comment: I guess the obvious question is why not switch to using ScalaTest?

Comment: Because a lot of code written with junit. Of couse new code writes with scalatest. But maybe it's not hard - rewrite all with scalatest...

Comment: Yeah, depending on the size of the code base that might be possible. Some [testing styles](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/selecting_a_style) are quite similar to JUnit. If you do stick with JUnit, it seems like your best bet is something that can take junit's xml reports and translate those to html. Side note, there is a `TestFrameworks.JUnit`  that you can add options to, but I don't think JUnit has a html reporter built in.

Comment: I do see some tools for taking the JUnit xml and translating to html after the fact, that might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to generate an HTML report in code inside my build.
I inspect every `.xml` file generated by JUnit, and convert the relevant data to an HTML table.
It is quite simple to do so.

This is for my legacy tests.
All new tests are written in ScalaTest.